# Do I have to overload functions for every different parameter?

Tags: c++, function, overloading

I want to create a function to simplify a list/vector. I can do it in python:

```
i = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
f = [1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5]
s = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]
def simplify(lst):
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return 0
    tmp = lst[0]
    for x in range(1, len(lst)):
        tmp += lst[x]
    print(tmp)
    return tmp
simplify(i)
simplify(f)
simplify(s)
```

but for c++ I would have to write the same function for many variable types (`long long`, `double`, `int`, `string`, `char`).
My question is, can I do in c++ like I did in python? (creating a single function for multiple types)

Comment: C++ has templates and that is what you want to use.

Comment: Read about function templates in your favourite C++ book.

Comment: "The sum of the elements in an empty list is -1" will cause many headaches. It is normally, and for good reasons, taken to be zero (or the empty string, in the case of strings).

Comment: you don't even need to write the function: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate

Comment: @molbdnilo Sorry for the return -1, I changed it. Would you recommend a good C++ book?

Comment: You should be able to find a suitable [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/4641116) on that list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is, can I do in c++ like I did in python? (creating a single function for multiple types)

Almost. A C++ function template is not a function, but using one can look indistinguishable from it.

You will also struggle with your choice of `-1` as the result if the sequence is empty, as `-1` is not a string.

```
template <typename Range>
std::ranges::range_value_t<Range> simplify(Range && range) {
    auto it = std::ranges::begin(range);
    if (it == std::ranges::end(range)) return -1; // this will fail for strings

    auto result = *it++;
    for (; it != std::ranges::end(range); ++it) {
        result += *it;
    }
    std::cout << result; // I assume this is for testing the function?
    return result;
}
```

If you make a different choice about what to do with an empty input, there is a function very similar to yours in the standard library:

```
template <typename Range>
std::ranges::range_value_t<Range> simplify(Range && range) {
    std::ranges::range_value_t<Range> zero {}; // 0 for numbers, empty string for strings, etc.
    return std::accumulate(std::ranges::begin(range), std::ranges::end(range), zero); 
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> i {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    std::vector<double> f {1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5};
    std::vector<std::string> s {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five"};
    std::cout << simplify(i);
    std::cout << simplify(f);
    std::cout << simplify(s);
}
```

[See it on coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d46bde0260e13c1a)